# What is the cumulative distribution function of T?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Define 3 independent random variables:

- X the time until your friend Alex calls, with an average waiting time for his call 1/λ (λ > 0)
- Y the time until your friend Jessica calls, with an average waiting time for her call 1/μ (μ > 0)
- Z the time until your friend Mick calls, with an average waiting time for her call 1/ν (ν > 0)

1. Let T be the time before any of those calls you. What is the cumulative distribution function of T?
2. Derive the p.m.f. of $I$:
   \begin{equation}
   I=
   \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if }X<min\{Y,Z\}\\
   1 & \text{if }Y<min\{X,Z\}\\
   2 & \text{if }Z<min\{X,Y\}\\
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}

**My Attempt**

I recognize each r.v. as exponential distributions, so we have
$$X\sim exp(1/\lambda)\implies f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}x}\implies F_X(x)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{\lambda}}$$
$$Y\sim exp(1/\mu)\implies f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\mu}e^{-\frac{1}{\mu}y}\implies F_Y(y)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{\mu}}$$
$$Z\sim exp(1/v)\implies f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{v}e^{-\frac{1}{v}z}\implies F_Z(z)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{v}}$$
Then $T=min(X,Y,Z)$ so our c.d.f. is
$$F_T(t)=F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y)\cdot F_Z(z)=(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\lambda}})(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\mu}})(1-e^{-\frac{t}{v}})$$
My question is what are the ranges for this c.d.f.? When is the probability $0$? When is it $1$?

I'm not sure what the second question is asking because isn't what's provided already a p.m.f.? What are we supposed to derive?

Comment: For the p.m.f, you should find $P(I=0), P(I=1), P(I=2)$ each in terms of $\lambda, \mu, \nu$

Comment: Someone could call almost immediately, though there is the possibility that nobody calls for a long time.  Like $X,Y,Z$, the support for T is $[0,\infty)$.  You should have $F_T(t)=0$ for $t \le 0$ and  $F_T(t)=1$ for $t=+\infty$. Your $F_T(t)=(1-e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}})(1-e^{-\frac{1}{\mu}})(1-e^{-\frac{1}{v}})$ looks wrong to me as (a) it does not have $t$ on the right hand side and (b) I do not understand the reciprocals and (c) it looks more like the cdf for $\max(X,Y,Z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the mean so the rate is the inverse of the provided quantities.

$$X\sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)\\
Y\sim \text{Exponential}(\mu)\\
Z\sim \text{Exponential}(\nu)$$

One way to find the cdf of $T$ is to consider:

$$\begin{split}Pr(T>t)&=Pr(\min\{X,Y,Z\}>t)\\
&=Pr(X>t)Pr(Y>t)Pr(Z>t)\\
&=e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\mu t}e^{-\nu t}\end{split}$$

Thus the cdf is $$1-e^{-(\lambda+\mu+\nu)t}, t>0$$

For part 2, the task is to find the probabilities. Note that $\min\{Y,Z\}\sim\text{Exponential}(\mu+\nu)$ by the previous problem. Define $W=\min\{Y,Z\}$.

$$\begin{split}Pr(X<W)&=\int_0^\infty Pr(X<W|W)f(W)dW\\
&=\int_0^\infty \left(1-e^{-\lambda w}\right)(\mu+\nu) e^{-(\mu+\nu)w}dw\\
&=1-\frac{\mu+\nu}{\lambda+\mu+\nu} \end{split}$$

By same pattern we can fil out

$$Pr(I=0)=1-\frac{\mu+\nu}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\\
Pr(I=1)=1-\frac{\lambda+\nu}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\\
Pr(I=2)=1-\frac{\lambda+\mu}{\lambda+\mu+\nu}$$